# Can one jquery fn function inherit from another?

Tags: jquery, inheritance

I am a beginner of Jquery and js,Now come to a situation:

1. I extend the $.fn to do some job.

   $.fn.extend({

   dofirstjob:function(seetings){

   //do the job code

   }
   })
2. Then , I need a another job similar to the first one. But,I still need some logic to do some different thing.
   I also don't want to copy and paste the code.I wonder if I can do someting with the inheritance. Just like:

   $.fn.extend({

   dofirstjob:function(seetings){

   //do the job code

   }

   doanotherjob:function(seetings){

   //inherit from dofirstjob()
   //overwrite some method from dofirstjob()

   var dosomethingdifferent = function(){

   }
   }
   })

Someone can show me some example codes?

thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry,i didn't make it clear.In the second function, I still need to overwrite some method inderited from the first one.